# The permission is it required to write data to google fit for the debug apk also?

Tags: google-fit

Yes i agree the verification  is required for the data to insert into the google fit but what about for the debug apk.
I am getting below error while testing for the debug apk "5000: Application needs OAuth consent from the user"

I have added the user to test, enabled fitness api & created the client ID aswell but why i am seeing this issue in the debug apk.

Please help me here

Comment: i am not clear on your response . The version should be same for production and debug right. could you please share me the link to find more details.

Comment: When the google fit verification for the scopes has been introduced?

Comment: Google Fit scopes are considered sensitive, therefore user consent is highly required and enabled.